# Getting a value in the readonly textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a textbox with an uneditable hardcoded value. I need help with retrieving it and display on button click. How can I validate dropdown to make it required? How can I display the selected value on this dropdown, I tried to use ng-model but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <input  class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="El Dix" readonly>
</div>
```

For the dropdown here's the code:-

```
<select ng-model="createCall_Urgency" class="form-control" >
  <option value="Low">Low</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
 <option value="Major">Major</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A `select` dropdown will always have some value, won't it?

Comment: put your question and req clearly please

Comment: Your question is not clear. You basically said that You want to display text from disabled input. But then you say something about select. What are you actually trying to achieve? Write down some scenario or something.

Comment: Please explain in more details, your requirements are not clear..

Comment: @philantrovert not really, the first option can be set to null or some thing like "Please Select:-". It's not obvious.

Comment: That's about 3 questions: 1) Retrieving the value on the readonly textbox. 2) How to force dropdown to be required. 3) How to display the selected option on the dropdown.

Comment: @eldix_ Even if you set it to *--Please Select--*, it won't be `null` if you will select `$(select).val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) I need help with retrieving it and display on button click

HTML

```
<button id="getValue" ng-click="getValue()">Get Value</button>
<input  class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" ng-model="focusedInput" readonly>
```

JS

```
$scope.focusedInput='El Dix';
$scope.getValue=function(){
    alert($scope.focusedInput);
}
```

> 2)How can I validate dropdown to make it required?

You need to use `required` property.

```
<select ng-model="createCall_Urgency" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="Low">Low</option>
   <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
   <option value="High">High</option>
   <option value="Major">Major</option>
</select>
```

> 3)How can I display the selected value on this dropdown ?

I would suggest you to create an array of objects and use `ngOptions` directive.

Something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('eApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.myOptions = [{
    "id": 'Low',
    "text": 'Low'
  }, {
    "id": 'Medium',
    "text": 'Medium'
  },
  {
    "id": 'High',
    "text": 'High'
  },{
    "id": 'Major',
    "text": 'Major'
  }];
  $scope.createCall_Urgency = $scope.myOptions[0];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="eApp">
  <div ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <select ng-model="createCall_Urgency" class="form-control" data-ng-options="options as options.text for options in myOptions">
  <option value="Low">Low</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
 <option value="Major">Major</option>
</select>
    {{createCall_Urgency.text}}
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I reject the `alert($('#focusedInput').val());` piece of code

Comment: A lot better ;)